# How can I see information about events in Meta Graph API Explorer

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api, request, get

I am trying to get information about my events on my Facebook site, but it doesn't work. I was trying to find solution online, but  I didn't find anything. Does anybody know what to do?

I send API request and I expected to get information about event on my Facebook web site:

[image: Meta Graph API Screenshoot]